# how to decode BodyBinary value in a Load Runner SOAP Request with GZIP Encryption

Tags: performance, encryption, soap, gzip, loadrunner

We need to decode the following BodyBinary value which is getting recorded for a ThickClient Application based on .Net WCF Web Services with Custom Bindings and GZIP Encoding

P.S: The body binary content was reduced to make it easier for posting here

```
web_custom_request("Service.svc", 
"[this is not a link]URL=webservice.svc", 
"Method=POST",
"Resource=0",
"RecContentType=application/x-gzip", 
"Referer=", 
"Snapshot=t1.inf",
"Mode=HTTP", 
"EncType=application/x-gzip", 
"BodyBinary=\\x1F\\x8B\\x08\\x00\\x00", 
 LAST);
```

We need to decode the BodyBinary for Parameterizing the input values for various other flows.

I have read about Data Format Extension which is a custom coding methodology introduced by HP but it's appearing very complex for us with limited coding background.

[Edit]
Current Approach:
We are not recording the application with VuGen and in fact are using Fiddler4(with GZIP and UNGZIP Custom Rules) to capture the Web Service Communication-UNGZIP the Request, then use the same in a Web Custom Request using lr_zip so that the Server can understand the request.

The main challenge here is that there is a lot of manual work in capturing all the Web Service Calls, UnGzipping them, creating a Custom Request and then hitting the Server.

If the same can be handled by Load Runner automatically or after recording with VuGen and doing some custom Decoding--Parameterization--Encoding-Posting to Server then it would drastically reduce our efforts.

```
char * param_xmlsource_GetUserAccess; 
param_xmlsource_GetUserAccess="Entire Soap Request(UnGzipped using Fiddler)";
web_set_user("{Username}","{Password}","{Env_URL}");
lr_save_string(lr_eval_string(param_xmlsource_GetUserAccess),"xmlsource_GetUserAccess");

lr_start_transaction("Transaction_GetUserAccess");

lr_zip("target=xmltarget_GetUserAccess", "source=xmlsource_GetUserAccess");

web_custom_request("web_custom_request",
"URL=WebService.svc",
"Method=POST",
"TargetFrame=",
"EncType=application/x-gzip",
"Resource=0",
"Referer=",
"Mode=HTTP",
"Body={xmltarget_GetUserAccess}",
LAST);

lr_end_transaction("Transaction_GetUserAccess",LR_AUTO);
```

[Edit]
updated the question by replacing the word "decrypt" with "decode" which is what is happening here.

Comment: You need a GZIP DFE, check if HPLN has one already. I will ask around here.

Comment: GZIP is not encryption. It is encoding.   You may download the standard GZIP algorithm and implement in LoadRunner or, as Buzzy notes, look for an existing DFE for this.

Comment: @JamesPulley as it turns out, there is already a function for that :). See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from our expert:
One of suggestions may be ContentEncoding=gzip argument and plain text request body in the script (should be converted manually)…
Just as sample:

Code:

```
web_reg_save_param("gzipped", "LB=","RB=","Search=Body",LAST);

web_custom_request("echo", 
    "URL=http://<myserver>/echo_post", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "ContentEncoding=gzip", 
    "Body=~!txtPassword=~#admin&~!txtLogin=~#admin&~!clientType=~#Swing&~!actionID=~#swing%2FcomsHome&~!alreadylogin=~#No", 
    LAST);


lr_unzip("source=gzipped","target=plain");
```

Output:

```
Action.c(9): t=350ms: 107-byte request body for "…” (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=1)
Action.c(9):     \x1F\x8B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0B\xABS,\xA9(\tH,..\xCF/J\xB1\xADSNL\xC9\xCD\xCCS\xAB
Action.c(9):     \x03\x89\xFA\xE4\xA7g\xE6!\t%\xE7d\xA6\xE6\x95\x84T\x16\xA4\x02\x05\x83\xCB3\xF3\xD2\x81\x82
Action.c(9):     \x89\xC9%\x99\xF9y\x9E.@\xA1b\x90\x90\xAA\x91[r~n\xB1G~n*H6\xA7(51\xA52\x07j\x92_>\x00\xF9
Action.c(9):     \xEB@\x99o\x00\x00\x00….
Action.c(9): t=384ms: 107-byte response body for "…" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=1)
Action.c(9):     \x1F\x8B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0B\xABS,\xA9(\tH,..\xCF/J\xB1\xADSNL\xC9\xCD\xCCS\xAB
Action.c(9):     \x03\x89\xFA\xE4\xA7g\xE6!\t%\xE7d\xA6\xE6\x95\x84T\x16\xA4\x02\x05\x83\xCB3\xF3\xD2\x81\x82
Action.c(9):     \x89\xC9%\x99\xF9y\x9E.@\xA1b\x90\x90\xAA\x91[r~n\xB1G~n*H6\xA7(51\xA52\x07j\x92_>\x00\xF9
Action.c(9):     \xEB@\x99o\x00\x00\x00

Action.c(9): Notify: Saving Parameter "gzipped = \x1f‹\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b«S,©(            H,..Ï/J±-SNLÉÍÌS«\x03‰úä§gæ!        %çd¦æ•„T\x16¤\x02\x05ƒË3óÒ\x81‚‰É%\x99ùyž.@¡b\x90\x90ª‘[r~n±G~n*H6§(51¥2\x07j’_>\x00ùë@\x99o\x00\x00\x00".

Action.c(22): Notify: Saving Parameter "plain = ~!txtPassword=~#admin&~!txtLogin=~#admin&~!clientType=~#Swing&~!actionID=~#swing%2FcomsHome&~!alreadylogin=~#No".
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @JamesPulley and Buzzy for your inputs..

I have updated my current approach to give you complete picture and the actual problem statement in a better way

Please do suggest if we are doing anything wrong here..

Comment: Right now we are exploring these links

1. How to enable GZIP compression for Web Vuser 
http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/​KM207128
2. How to compress and decompress data
http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/​KM213957

Comment: You should try to ask this question in the LoadRunner Support Forum - (http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/bd-p/sws-LoadRunner_SF) They can help you more

Answer (score 0):

Jus to add my cents worth, ContentEncoding = gzip will work fine as long as winit mode is enabled. In our case, our scripts have to fire async calls and hence we cannot use winit mode. I raised the same issue with LR support and they really didn't have much to say about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar issue many times.. you can try this

1. selecting one of the compression method

2.save script

3. then set it back to "None"

Refer this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQYZH.jpg